# Existence of a global limit in $L^1([-N,N])$ for each $N\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let $(f_n)_n$ be sequence of functions $f_n\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ such that for each $N\in \mathbb{N}$, $(f_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^1([-N,N])$. Then for each $N$, $(f_n)_n$ converges to a function $f_N\in L^1([-N,N])$. Do I need to use something like Zorn's Lemma or axiom of choice to conclude that there exists a function $f\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $(f_n)_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^1$ in each compact interval ? If so, then how to use it ?

Comment: Just paste together the $L^1[-n,n]$ limits of this sequence noting that they agree almost everywhere on their common domains.

Comment: @hot_queen Yes, I see that, the function $f$ I see it in my mind. It is well defined. But if I say "let $f$ be the function defined on the whole real line such that the restriction of $f$ on each interval $[-N,N]$ equals $f_N$". Did I just used something like Zorn' lemma or a kind of choice ? I mean what kind of axiom insures the existence of such a function ? I just think like this because in general existence of extension of functions usually use something like Zorn's lemma, for example the existence of an extension of a functional in Hahn-Banach theorem.

Comment: I dont think you used anything since $f_N$ are uniquely defined (modulo null) so is $f$.

Comment: Or maybe I should say: Let "$\leq$" be the order defined on the set $A=\{f_N:N\in  \mathbb{N}\}$ by: $f_N \leq f_M$ if $N \leq M$. And then consider  $f=\sup_{g \in A} g$.

Comment: No disrespect intended but you are overcomplicating things.

Comment: Yeah, I have just realized I am over complicating, the set of limits here is already totally ordered, so no need to use Zorn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Zorn's lemma. The function $f$ can be defined explicitly as
$$
f_1\chi_{\{|x|\le 1\}}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty f_{n} \chi_{\{n-1<|x|\le n\}}
$$
which is evidently in $L^1_{\rm loc}$ (on every bounded interval, only finitely many terms are nonzero). The convergence of $f_n$ to $f$ on every bounded interval follows from the fact that the restriction of $f$ to $[-N,N]$ is 
$$
f_1\chi_{\{|x|\le 1\}}+\sum_{n=2}^N f_{n} \chi_{\{n-1<|x|\le n\}} = f_1+\sum_{n=2}^N f_{n} \chi_{\{|x|\le n\}} - \sum_{n=2}^N f_{n} \chi_{\{|x|\le n-1\}}  \\ =
f_1\chi_{\{|x|\le 1\}}+\sum_{n=2}^N f_{n} \chi_{\{|x|\le n\}} - \sum_{n=2}^N f_{n-1} \chi_{\{|x|\le n-1\}} = f_N \chi_{|x|\le N}
$$